# Javascript random quiz but more than 1 asked

Tags: javascript, random

I have made this code which displays a random question each time a page is refreshed or clicked. However, i want it to display not just one random question but 3 different ones which are randomized each time. How would i do this!

Thanks!

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
        var question= new Array(5)
        question[0] = "Question 1"
        question[1] = "Question 2"
        question[2] = "Question 3"
        question[3] = "Question 4 "
        question[4] = "Question 5) "
        question[5] = "Question 6) "
        var rand_int= Math.floor(Math.random()*5);

        document.write(question[rand_int]);
        </script>
```

Comment: It appears you already have code to execute this once. In an effort to help you arrive at the answer yourself, think about how you can execute the same logic 'n' different times (or 3 in your case).

Comment: if i use a for loop but im not too sure how and would take me a while to do

Comment: Knowing what you need to do is half the battle, applying it would be the other half. With the answer(s) posted below, I strongly suggest you try to understand the `for` loop syntax without blindly copying/pasting the answer directly into your code.

Comment: In addition to Anthony's suggestions, it's also worth noting that you probably don't want the same question listed twice... running a "random question selector" code multiple times might yield the same question multiple times. To compensate for this, you'll need to keep track of questions you have already yielded, and not yield them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 

var question= new Array(5)
question[0] = "Question 1"
question[1] = "Question 2"
question[2] = "Question 3"
question[3] = "Question 4"
question[4] = "Question 5"
question[5] = "Question 6"

var numberOfQuestions = 3;
var questions = [];

for(var i=0;i<numberOfQuestions;i++){
    var rand_int= Math.floor(Math.random()*question.length);
          while(question[rand_int] == null){
    var rand_int= Math.floor(Math.random()*question.length);
    }
    questions.push(question[rand_int]);
    question.splice(rand_int, 1);
}

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    document.write(questions[i] + "<br />");
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would stay away from `document.write` -- this overwrites the page each time. Instead you should append to a DOM element.

```
<div id="questionsContainer"></div>
```

Assign this `div` to a variable:

```
var questionDiv = document.getElementById("questionDiv");
```

You'll need a new random number each time one of the questions from the list is pulled. Define the number of questions you want to show:

```
var questionsVisible = 3;
```

Loop over the array of questions with the `questionsVisible` as the stopping point:

```
for (var i = 0; i < questionsVisible; i++) {
    var rand_int = Math.floor(Math.random() * question.length); //use the length of the array, not a magic number

    //Create and append
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.text = question[rand_int];
    questionDiv.appendChild(span);

    //Splice the used question
    question.splice(rand_int, 1);
}
```