# Random if condition that runs indefinite?

Tags: javascript

Hello I am making a question form in JavaScript and I am trying to make it work out so that the questions run always and not stop at 4 in a random sorted order. So each time a random question is asked in a random order with never ending. I am running my code in a loop if statement.

```js
var questionNum = 0;
var question = '<h1>What is your name?</h1>';

var output = document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = question;

function bot() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    console.log(input);

    if (questionNum == 0) {
      var audio = new Audio('music/openmind.ogg');
      audio.play();
    output.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello ' + input + '!</h1>';
    document.getElementById("input").value = "";
    question = '<h1>How old are you?</h1>';
    setTimeout(timedQuestion, 2000);
    }

    else if (questionNum == 1) {

    output.innerHTML = '<h1>That means you were born in ' + (2017 - input) + '.</h1>';
    document.getElementById("input").value = "";
    question = '<h1>where are you from?</h1>';
    setTimeout(timedQuestion, 2000);
    }

    else if (questionNum == 2) {
      var audio = new Audio('music/beone.ogg');
      audio.play();
      output.innerHTML =  '<h1>You are from ' + (input) + '.</h1>';
      document.getElementById("input").value = "";
      question = '<h1>Do you eat healthy?</h1>';
      setTimeout(timedQuestion, 2000);
    }

    else if (questionNum == 3) {
      var audio = new Audio('music/becoming.ogg');
      audio.play();
      output.innerHTML = '<h1>Acording to my data you are eating ' + (input) + ' and that is healthy!</h1>'


    }
}

function timedQuestion() {
    output.innerHTML = question;
}


$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    bot();
    questionNum++;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #8dd8f8;
}

h1, p {

 text-align: center;
 color: #323330;
 font-size:  100px;
}


p {
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="well">
<div id="output"></div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Responce:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" value="">
   </div>
  </div>




</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript random quiz but more than 1 asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440399/javascript-random-quiz-but-more-than-1-asked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the questions and their responses are placed in object instead of using an `if..else` structure, the code (and maintainability) will get a lot easier.
Perhaps I've mixed up the audio, but the idea remains the same: each object contains the question, an optional audio file and a response function:

```js
let questions = [
  {text:'What is your name?', audio:'music/openmind.ogg', response : input => 'Hello ' + input + '!' },
  {text:'How old are you?', response : input => 'That means you were born in ' + (2017 - input) + '.'},
  {text:'Where are you from?', audio:'music/beone.ogg', response: input => 'You are from ' + (input) + '.'},
  {text: 'Do you eat healthy?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to my data you are eating ' + (input) + ' and that is healthy!'}
 ];

let output = $('#output'),
    input = $("#input"),
    curQuestion;

function ask() {
  let qi = Math.floor(Math.random() *  questions.length); //depending on your needs, a check could be added if it's been asked directly before or only recycle questions when all are asked
  curQuestion = questions[qi];
  setOutput(curQuestion.text);
  input.val('');  
}

ask(); //first call

function respond(){
  let q = curQuestion;
  if(q.audio)
    new Audio(q.audio).play();
  setOutput(q.response(input.val()));
  setTimeout(ask, 2000);
}

function setOutput(txt){
  output.html($('<h1>').text(txt));
}

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    respond();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #8dd8f8;
}

h1, p {

 text-align: center;
 color: #323330;
 font-size:  100px;
}


p {
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="well">
<div id="output"></div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Responce:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" value="">
   </div>
  </div>




</div>
```